# Vertical Scroll in react slick is moving with the body scoll

Tags: scroll, react-slick

i am making a project using Nextjs and React slick for vertical scroll. The vertical scroll works fine on the laptop screen but on the phone the vertical scroll misbehaves as the whole body scroll when i use the react-slick scroll..
is there a solution to this ?

```
const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    speed: 2000,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
```